# Не работает justify-content: center; для inline-flex!

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox

Подскажите, почему не работают значения `justify-content` для `inline-flex`-элемента. Когда меняю на `display: flex;` , то работает.

**Мне нужно, чтобы навигационное меню было при помощи flexbox и на одной строке с заголовком "Interactive Agency".**

```css
html,
body,
h1,
.menu {
  font-family: 'Gamja Flower', cursive;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background: url(Layer1.png) no-repeat center top / cover;
  height: 1200px;
}

header h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <h1><b>Interactive</b>Agency</h1>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Offer</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что, когда у элемента  `display: inline-flex;` его ширина исходит от контента

```css
html,
body,
h1,
.menu {
  font-family: 'Gamja Flower', cursive;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background: url(Layer1.png) no-repeat center top / cover;
  height: 1200px;
}

header h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  background: red;
  padding: 5px;
}

.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  background: brown;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <h1><b>Interactive</b>Agency</h1>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Offer</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

================================================

А когда у элемента `display: flex;` его ширина исходит от  его родителя, ну или от каких то других параметров

```css
html,
body,
h1,
.menu {
  font-family: 'Gamja Flower', cursive;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background: url(Layer1.png) no-repeat center top / cover;
  height: 1200px;
}

header h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  background: red;
  padding: 5px;
}

.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  background: brown;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <h1><b>Interactive</b>Agency</h1>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Offer</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Т.е. с inline-flex не получится перемещать элементы вдоль главной оси?

Comment: Почему? Ты можешь зажать контейнеру ширину больше чем контент и будет работать.

Comment: Спасибо, @Air , Ваш совет помог!